# Apache2 - Broken images load from remote server

Tags: image, apache2, ubuntu-18.04

I have an apache2 server running under Ubuntu 18.04

Strangely, apache cannot display images, event though my browser load it with a 200 response message.

If I trigger directly the image link, I can download it successfully, but the image cannot be open (wrong format), like it is broken.

This website used to work on another apache2 with approximately the same configuration.

I have tried to put an image file into the default folder (var/www) and display it with a simple src, it works !

My website that refuses to display images has this configuration in apache2.conf :

```
<Directory /var/www>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

And the virtualhost looks like this :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName nasticot.lan
    DocumentRoot /var/www/nasticot.lan
    ServerAlias www.nasticot.lan
</VirtualHost>
```

/var/www is an SMB share mounted from a remote container. 
The server has full rights on every file into this share (777)

There is also an .htaccess file at the root of the website

```
# Rewrite URL like xxx/yyy/zzz in index.php?controleur=xxx&action=yyy&id=zzz
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]*)/?([a-zA-Z]*)?/?([a-zA-Z0-9]*)?/?$ index.php?controleur=$1&action=$2&id=$3 [NC,L]
```

[EDIT]

strangely, apache2 add content to my images on load.

I've verified one more time that my images are displayable directly in the folder read by my apache2 server, and it works.

If I download the image locally from the browser, the image has a few more line added to it.

[EDIT-01] :
My /var/www is a mounted share, located in my fileserver.
I found that this is the problem. If I copy the content of one of my website locally, images are displayed.

Event though I've full access to the mounted share :

```
root@coruscant:/var/www/nasticot.lan/Content/img/icon# ls -la /var/www
total 4
drwxrwxrwx  2 root www-data    0 Mar 20 15:54 .
drwxr-xr-x 14 root root     4096 Mar 20 19:31 ..
drwxrwxrwx  2 root www-data    0 Mar 24 11:08 nasticot.lan
```

And this is the share configuration in the fileserver :

```
[WWW]
    path = /media/share/www
    browseable = yes
    writeable = yes
    read only = no
    force create mode = 0770
    force directory mode = 2770
    valid users = @sambashare
```

And finally, the fstab file on the webserver :

```
//192.168.0.53/WWW       /var/www    cifs    credentials=/root/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,gid=www-data       0 0
```

Images file are loaded (200 OK) but broken ..

[EDIT-02]

Still looking for a solution, I'm pretty sure it's not a permission issu, the problem always appears even with 777 ...

I wonder if php could break the image on load, I tried to set

*php.ini*

```
error_reporting = E_ALL
error_log = /var/log/php_errors.log
```

But I got nothing written into this log file so .. don't really know where to search ..

Please any help would be very appreciated

Any idea ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A workaround, but not an explanation as to the cause, is to add the `EnableSendFile on` directive in the `Directory` block.

I say it's a workaround because in my diagnosis of the same problem (Environment: Laravel Homestead 11 Vagrant guest, Windows 10 host using Hyper-V and smb mounts), it only happens if you use HTTP - HTTPS works just fine, which makes it the *weirdest* thing

Comment: I found the same solution a few weeks ago, I was about to post it here and I saw you answer ! This directive resolved the problem ! My images are now correctly loaded.

Thank you very much for your support ;)